# How to forbid a release:perform from child module of a multi modules maven project?

Tags: maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

I've a multi-module maven project which is piloted by a pom reactor.
The reactor valid that all modules versions are identical with the maven-enforcer-plugin.
When I release the entire project from the pom-reactor, all is fine. All versions are correctly set and svn tags are created.

Now, my question is about, how can I forbid the release from a child module ?

Comment: Simply you can't...it will fail but you can't forbid it...

Comment: @khmarbaise Why do you think it will fail ? In fact, it doesn't fail.. ><'

Comment: It fails cause it's simply wrong to release only a single child and afterwards you will get in trouble...

Comment: @khmarbaise : Again, it doesn't fail if we try to release a single child... so my  target is to forbid it or to make sure the release will fail